# Why isn't Form.Select recognized in my simple react-bootstrap app, following the react-bootstrap documentation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I am a "react-bootstrap with hooks" first-timer and I am creating a simple form.  I am following the react-bootstrap documentation's example and I am running into a problem with select/option form elements.  Regular text input fields render normally without an error. Select statements seem to blow things up.

Here is my code:

```
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function FormComponentName(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Search Form</h1>

            <Form>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="searchState">
                    <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Select defaultValue="State...">
                        <option>State...</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                </Form.Group>
               <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Search Data
                </Button>

            </Form>


        </>
    )

}
```

Here is the yarn error message:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `FormComponentName`.
```

And from the console:

```
index.js:1 Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at FormComponentName.js:14.
    at FormComponentName
```

Do I need to install an additional module, or is it something more obvious?

Comment: I'm not that well known with react, but I don't know where you get this setup from. I don't see anything like it on either https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/04/11/react-hooks-bootstrap-alert-notifications or https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html. Can you point to the documentation you are using?

Comment: The code seems fine. It's a common export, import issue. export default class or function doesn't require curly braces when importing and export only require curly braces, you most likely forgot using curly braces, when you are importing the function. That's one possible solution

Comment: Here are the relevant react-bootstrap docs: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/forms/#forms-select

Comment: If I take out the code block containing the select form elements and replace it with text inputs, radio buttons, and checkbox inputs, the form renders normally.  For some reason "Form.Select" isn't recognized.  I know I can work around it using other options for the select input, but I don't understand why this code isn't working, since it follows the developer's sample code closely.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of `Form.Select`, you can use:

```
<Form.Control as="select">...</Form.Control>
```

Answer (score 12):

Form.Select appears to be a beta feature that isn't implemented in current the production version of bootstrap-react.  That is the reason why the above code wasn't working.

Comment: This is a bit useless if true... their documentation does not make this clear at all. I am getting the same error as OP. If a feature isn't working they should not have it in their docs: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-select

Answer (score 5):

Full code will be look like as defined below

```
 <Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Status</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select">
      <option>Active</option>
      <option>Inactive</option>
    </Form.Control>
  </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the following code:

```
                    <Form.Select className="text-center">
                        <option>Alfie-Lee Powell</option>
                        <option>Amir Conley</option>
                        <option>Barney Hirst</option>
                        <option>Ciaron Robinson</option>
                        <option>Claude Whyte</option>
                        <option>Ismael English</option>
                        <option>Pranav Smith</option>
                        <option>Tamanna Warner</option>
                        <option>Thierry Vaughn</option>
                    </Form.Select>
```

Use this instead

```
                    <Form.Control as="select" className="text-center">
                        <option>Alfie-Lee Powell</option>
                        <option>Amir Conley</option>
                        <option>Barney Hirst</option>
                        <option>Ciaron Robinson</option>
                        <option>Claude Whyte</option>
                        <option>Ismael English</option>
                        <option>Pranav Smith</option>
                        <option>Tamanna Warner</option>
                        <option>Thierry Vaughn</option>
                    </Form.Control>
```

As of 7/21/22 it is still in beta and is prone to error

Answer (score 0):

In order for "submit" to show it as a json you need to provide the "name" parameter. Like this:

```js
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function FormComponentName(props) {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Search Form</h1>

            <Form>

                <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="searchState">
                    <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>


//The name of the param will become the key in your json


                    <Form.Select defaultValue="State..." name="myParameter">


                        <option>State...</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                </Form.Group>
               <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Search Data
                </Button>

            </Form>


        </>
    )

}
```